# React Native Change State from Custom Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, components

I have custom picker component and i want to update states on selectedValue and  onValueChange event. It works fine if i add picker directly in render section but due to duplication of code i decided to convert my pickers into custom component. So i did it like this:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Modal,
    ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';
import { Item, Picker } from 'native-base'

const CustomPicker = props => {
    const {
        pickerLabel,
        selectedVal,
        onChangeVal,
        pickerStyle,
        pickerData,
        ...attributes
    } = props;

    return (
        <Picker
            selectedValue={selectedVal}
            style={[pickerStyle]}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({onChangeVal: itemValue})}>
            <Picker.Item label={pickerLabel} value={''}/>
            {pickerData.map((item, key) => (
                <Picker.Item label={item} value={item} key={key}/>)
            )}
        </Picker>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default CustomPicker;
```

I call on different component like this:

```
<CustomPicker pickerLabel={"Select User"} selectedVal={this.state.selectedUser} pickerStyle={styles.picker} pickerData={this.state.userList} onChangeVal={this.state.selectedUser} />
```

Label + data is populating in picker nicely but issue is coming on events. Its not updating state on picking data, What am i missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a function in the parent component to change the values, since you're trying to change the `state` in a `stateless component`

Instead what you need to do is

**Parent Component**

```
onChange = (itemValue, itemIndex) => {
  // Set the state here and update as required
}

<CustomPicker pickerLabel={"Select User"} selectedVal={this.state.selectedUser} pickerStyle={styles.picker} pickerData={this.state.userList} onChangeVal={this.onChange} />
```

**Child Component**

```
onValueChange={onChangeVal}>
```

**For Multiple Pickers :**

**Parent Component**

```
state = {
  user: [
         {value: 'Something', key: 0, label: 'Select User', userList: [//...Some Array here]},
         {value: 'Something Else', key: 1, label: 'Dont Select User', userList: [//...Some Array here]}
    ]
}

onChange = (itemValue, itemIndex, pickerIndex) => {
      // Update the states based on the pickerIndex
    }

const {user} = this.state

// Use a map here

user.map((data, index) => (
      <CustomPicker key={index} index={index} pickerLabel={data.label} selectedVal={data.value} pickerStyle={styles.picker} pickerData={data.userList} onChangeVal={this.onChange} />
))
```

**Child Component**

```
const {
        index, <== Picker Index
        pickerLabel,
        selectedVal,
        onChangeVal,
        pickerStyle,
        pickerData,
        ...attributes
    } = props;

<Picker
            selectedValue={selectedVal}
            style={[pickerStyle]}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.props.onChangeVal(itemValue, itemIndex, index)}> <== Pass picker value to the parent
```

Comment: is there any other way to do this without making a method. Because i have 8-9 pickers on a screen and by using your approach i had to make 8-9 methods.

Comment: You dont need to make 8 9 methods, you can make an array of values in initialState and update them based on the index of currently selected Picker

Comment: I don't like this approach. Any other way? can i directly pass to component as props

Comment: You can always pass directly to component as props, but can't update it since the values need to be passed to the parent component. Other way would be to use redux.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit how can i handle multiple picker with multiple states? how can onChange method differentiate for different picker, can you provide an example?

Comment: Checkout the above explanation